# google oauth refresh token long lived solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Google OAuth 2.0 Access Token's have an expiry time. I have integrated the Google Calendar API into my Ruby application however the problem is access token is expiring. How can I make the access token long lived one.

```
cal.login_with_refresh_token('ksdjkf_sdfkasdhfjhaskjdhfkasdhfkasjdlfasld')
```

> {
>     "access_token" => "ksdjkf_sdfkasdhfjhaskjdhfkasdhfkasjdlfasld",
>
> "token_type" => "Bearer",
>
> "expires_in" => 2324
>
> }

How to make this a long lived one which means untill unless he revokes access from his Google account user can be able to fetch his Calendar events.

Comment: @DaImTo made corrections thanks

Comment: Request offline access to get a refresh token and use the refresh token to get a new access token.  Sorry I cant help with Ruby.

Comment: @DaImTo you didn't answer the question. I'm having the same issue. ```Use the refresh token to get a new access token``` is rather vague and doesn't show any examples. Can you elaborate how this is done. I know there must be some sort of API to allow silent token refresh without forcing the user to reauthenticate any time the token expires. My use case is NodeJS and I'm using the Google OAUTH NodeJS Library.

Comment: @user15155716 you are commenting on a question that is six years old.  I am not a ruby developer so i cant give you any help on ruby.  You should try searching [Ruby sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/samples/cli/lib/samples/drive.rb)  there are a lot of samples for the client library.  fact of the matter is that if its set up properly the client library should handel all refreshing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to create a long-lived OAuth token for the Google API:

1. visit http://console.developers.google.com
2. API Manager
3. Credentials
4. Create Credentials (OAuth client ID)
5. Application type: Web Application
6. Authorised redirect URIs: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

   - the resultant client ID / client secret is for your access token
7. visit: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
8. Click the settings icon to show the OAuth 2.0 configuration
9. Tick 'Use your own OAuth credentials'
10. Enter the OAuth Client ID and OAuth Client secret that you have just created
11. Check the entry for 'Calendar API v3' in the scopes field and click 'Authorize APIs'
12. Click 'Allow'
13. Click 'Exchange authorization code for tokens'

    - now you have a Refresh token and Access token for your client id / secret

Here's an example of using that oauth token with the **ruby-api-client** gem to talk to the Google Play API using signet. You should be able to modify this example to instead use the calendar API pretty easily:

https://gist.github.com/jkotchoff/e60fdf048ec443272045

> Note this was inspired by: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc